Joining together columns from different tables in a SQL database
I want to join the sex of driver (from vehicle table), sex of casualty (from casualty table), speed limit (from accident table) and age of vehicle (from vehicle table) for accidents in a particular location code
I ran this code
stoke_accident = cur.execute("SELECT vehicle.sex_of_driver, casualty.sex_of_casualty, accident.speed_limit, vehicle.age_of_vehicle FROM accident JOIN vehicle ON vehicle.accident_index = accident.accident_index JOIN casualty ON accident.accident_index = casualty.accident_index AND vehicle.vehicle_reference = casualty.vehicle_reference JOIN lsoa ON accident.lsoa_of_accident_location = lsoa.lsoa01cd WHERE lsoa.lsoa01nm = 'Stoke Upon Trent';")
acc_list = stoke_accident.fetchall()

This is the SQL query:
SELECT 
    vehicle.sex_of_driver,
    casualty.sex_of_casualty,
    accident.speed_limit,
    vehicle.age_of_vehicle
FROM
    accident
JOIN
    vehicle ON vehicle.accident_index = accident.accident_index
JOIN
    casualty ON accident.accident_index = casualty.accident_index
             AND vehicle.vehicle_reference = casualty.vehicle_reference
JOIN
    lsoa ON accident.lsoa_of_accident_location = lsoa.lsoa01cd
WHERE
    lsoa.lsoa01nm = 'Stoke Upon Trent';

I expected to get a list of the details I wanted - but got nothing ...

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question description.

Also, please don't use all CAPS in your title


sqlite and mysql are two different databe products with different implementations of sql. Which one do you actually use? What does this question have to do with pandas and dataframes? 2) Please provide sample data, expected results, and actual results, otherwise we can't really tell you why a query did not return any data.


Help us help you - share some sample data, the result you get for it and the result you're trying to get

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Take smaller steps. Start with a SELECT from one table, verify the result. JOIN a second table, verify the result. JOIN a third table, etc.
